# One NGRX store, multiple Angular Applications

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, store, ngrx-store

So I'm a little bit nob with this. Hope you can apologise me.

I'm trying to insert multiple Angular elements (web components) into a Prestashop module, which is PHP. As there is not a single Angular App with many modules, I cannot use the store to send data from an element to another.

I have thought of creating a library which is in charge of creating the NGRX store, and kind of saves it to window.store (for instance), so the same store can be used by multiple independent angular apps. The issue here is that I have to invoke the library in many Angular elements, so I'm injecting different stores in the constructor. Am I right?

For instance:

```
import {
  ActionReducer,
  ActionReducerFactory,
  ActionReducerMap,
  ActionReducerMap,
  ActionsSubject,
  ReducerManager,
  ReducerManagerDispatcher,
  StateObservable,
  Store,
} from '@ngrx/store'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const storeName = 'store'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreSyncService {

  store: any = null

  // option 1 constructor:
  // are we, when including the library in others angular apps, instantiating store over and over?
  constructor(private store: Store) {
     if (window[storeName]) {
      this.store = window[storeName]
    } else{
      window[storeName] = this.store
    }
  }

  // option 2 constructor (please apologise me as I don't know how injection works very well).
  // Any link to clarify this is welcome
  constructor() {
    if (window[storeName]) {
      this.store = window[storeName]
    } else{
      const stateObservable$: StateObservable = new Observable()
      const actionsObserver: ActionsSubject = new ActionsSubject()

      const dispatcher: ReducerManagerDispatcher = new ActionsSubject()
      const initialState = {}
      const reducers: ActionReducerMap<any, any> = {}
      const reducerFactory: ActionReducerFactory<any, any> =  whatever

      const reducerManager: ReducerManager = new ReducerManager(dispatcher, initialState, reducers, reducerFactory)
      this.store = new Store(stateObservable$, actionsObserver, reducerManager)
      window[storeName] = this.store
    }
  }

  public getStore = () => this.store

  public addReducer = (reducerName: string, reducer: ActionReducer<any>) => this.store.addReducer(reducerName, reducer)

  public removeReducer = (reducerName: string) => this.store.removeReducer(reducerName)

}
```

So to recap, if I want to share state between more than one independent angular app, how would you do?

I tried with localStorage, adding events to synchronize NGRX state with data in local storage and viceversa, but resulted, some times in a infinite loop and sometimes in edge cases in which data was not sync.

Thanks for your help and comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now, I kind of found a workaround to avoid the double instantiation of the store. Using a conditional injector.

```
  import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

  ...


  constructor(private injector : Injector) {
    if (window[storeName]) {
      this.store = window[storeName]
    } else{
      this.store = this.injector.get<Store>(Store);
      window[storeName] = this.store
    }
  }
```

I still haven't tested it to share data between the independent applications. Let's hope it works.

Any advice is always welcomed!!

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem. I'd be interested in hearing how this approach worked for you.

Comment: Hey @tkooser So it's working very well, but be aware that depending on what you want to do you'll probably need to create your own Effects/Actions and so on... It's been a while since I did this, and I ended up kind of forking the NGRX repo and adapting it to my necessities. So go ahead with this and if you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask